# SQL Server, Incorrect syntax, Convert to datetime

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Using ASP classic, I want to convert a date `Tue, 21 Apr 2020 12:23:00 GMT` to the format `AAAA-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` to insert it into a SQL Server 2008 database.

My code:

```
CONVERT('Tue, 21 Apr 2020 12:23:00 GMT', GETDATE(), 20)
```

I get this error:

> Incorrect syntax to 'Tue, 21 Apr 2020 12:23:00 GMT'.

Comment: Just as a note: SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2 are **out of extended support** by now - https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/the-end-of-sql-server-2008-and-2008-r2-extended-support/ - time to upgrade!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that dates in SQL Server don't actually have any internal string format.  Rather, they are stored as binary.  One option here would be to take the following substring of the your input timestamp, and then use `TRY_CONVERT` to marshall it over to a bona fide datetime inside SQL Server:

```
Tue, 21 Apr 2020 12:23:00 GMT  <-- start with this input
21 Apr 2020 12:23:00           <-- convert this string to datetime
```

Sample code:

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT 'Tue, 21 Apr 2020 12:23:00 GMT' AS dt
)

SELECT
    dt,
    TRY_CONVERT(datetime, SUBSTRING(dt, 6, LEN(dt) - 9)) AS dt_out
FROM yourTable;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

**Edit:**

If you are using an earlier version of SQL Server, then you can use `CONVERT` with format mask 106, using the same substring as above:

```
SELECT
    dt,
    CONVERT(datetime, SUBSTRING(dt, 6, LEN(dt) - 9), 106) AS dt_out
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: I use sql server 2008, I can't use TRY_CONVERT with a compatibility lower than 110

Comment: @user_1330 Then use `CONVERT` with format mask `106`, q.v. my updated answer.

Comment: using insertion directly from sql server works very well but using asp classic doesn't work, would you have an idea please?
Error: Failure to convert date and/or time from a string.

Comment: I would have to see your ASP code (and I don't know it very well).  Assuming the above query fixes your immediate SQL Server problem, you might want to open a new question for the ASP issue.